# Undefined reference from shared library in static one

Tags: gcc, linker

For example, I have 3 different instances:

1. Shared library with undefined reference "get_object" and definition
   "x"
2. Static library with definitions "get_object", "y".
3. <strike>Binary file</strike> Object file with undefined references "x" and "y".

Am I right that linker can resolve all this symbols when I'll try to compile and link all this stuff together?

Main point of my worry is symbol "get_object".
Can linker resolve such references between shared and static libraries?

Comment: 3. is an object file, not a binary executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static libraries are just an agglomeration of object files (their members), perhaps with a [ranlib(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ranlib.1.html) generated index.

On Linux, if you link an object file (3) `foo.o` with a static library (2) `libee.a` and a shared library (1)  `libyz.so` and if you pass `-rdynamic` at [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) time (i.e. `gcc -rdynamic foo.o libee.a libyz.so -o myprog` or `gcc -rdynamic foo.o -lee -lyz -o myprog`) then [dynamic linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) would resolve the `get_object` name at dynamic link time (in `ld-linux.so`)

Details are explained in [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) wikipage and Drepper's paper: [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf). Read also Levine's book: [*Linkers and loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) & [ld(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) man page.